# How to force type on return value in a generic class?

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have a generic class:

```java
public final  class MyClass<T> {
    private List<T> list;

    public MyClass(){

    }
}
```

Two questions:

I want to force the user to create a generic return type as well, this is why I created a generic class but apparently he can do this:

```java
MyClass item = new MyClass();
```

and also this:

```java
MyClass item = new MyClass<Customer>();
```

I want to force the developer to define their return type with the same type they supplied so they would only be able to do:

```java
MyClass<Customer> item= new MyClass<Customer>();
```

The purpose of this class is to get a type in the constructor, let's say class `Customer`, and create a generic list of that type but since the return object is passed between the application layer I want to force it to have a signature `MyClass<Customer>` so its easy to understand the type of list it contains.

Comment: You cannot enforce generic typing on the caller-side. This is due to the fact how generics work (and this is due to the fact that java is backwards-compatible).

Comment: You can’t.  But the compiler will issue a “raw type” warning to that developer.  If the developer chooses to ignore that warning, they do so at their own peril.

Comment: There is no way that you can prevent people from using your Generic class as a raw type (unless you have control over the compiler they are using). But honestly though, if you need to tell your Java developers to not use raw types, then you should probably get new developers because not using raw types should be as normal and common sense as not writing all code in one single line.

Comment: Perhaps you can produce an example why you think your desired enforcements are necessary and not just delusional

Comment: Java Type Erasure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: The duplicate is not an exact duplicate but it contains all the information relevant. And since the only valid answer on this question is basically "No" there is no real point in keeping this question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The purpose of this class is to get a type in the constructor, let's say class Customer, and create a generic list of that type...

No, you don't need this as the developer of `MyClass`. You can safely do something like this in your code (and it has nothing to do with whether the caller will use the raw `MyClass` type):

```
public final  class MyClass<T> {
    private List<T> list;

    public MyClass(){
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Beside the fact that Java allows this for good (and practical) reasons, your type parameter being unbounded simply suggests that you yourself don't care much either (Java uses `Object` by default when `MyClass` is used instead of `MyClass<Something>`).

If, however, what you're looking for is dynamic behavior based on the type, like instantiating elements dynamically, then the best is to take the class instance itself from your caller:

```
public final  class MyClass<T> {
    private Class<T> type;
    private List<T> list;

    public MyClass(Class<T> type){
        this.type = type;
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //then use type to perform your dynamic behavior on the element type
}
```

This will force your callers to send a type, therefore making it almost pointless for them to use the raw type. But you should have a reason to do this too.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, for backwards compatibility reasons generics are not forced.

If you ask the type class as constructor parameter your developers will have to think of a type:

```
private static class MyClass<T> {
    private List<T> list;

    public MyClass(Class<T> clazz){

    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    MyClass myclass=new MyClass(Object.class);
}
```

But as you can see, they can always pass Object :)